# Perl: how to make variables from requiring script available in required script

Tags: perl, variables, scope, require, required

example

out.pl:

```
(my|our|local|global|whatever???) var = "test";
require("inside.pm");
```

inside.pm:

```
print $var;
```

I don't want to use packages - it's overwhelming my needs :) 
thanks!

Comment: I don't think, that you really want to use a variable in a module, which has to be specified by the executing sctript. It's not even very beautiful if you turned it around (using a module var in your script). I would strongly recommend to pass the required value in a function call. Or instead of `require "inside.pm";` you could also write `use inside $var` to pass any arguments to the module. See [perldoc use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html)

Comment: thanks for reply. the required script shouldn't be considered as a module - it'd be very small piece of code that's included in major script and may be changed by other person in very restricted way. So the variable from OUTER script is asked to be available for required script

Comment: Will your outer script be more than a config file (i.e. setting some variables) ? If so, you could just use a config file and not a executable script...

Comment: What do you mean by "in a restricted way" . Could the other person make a change that accidentally or delibrately breaks the script.  Agree with @Jan that a config file might be better.

Comment: i'd say in well-defined way, not restricted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work with `our`.

```
$ cat out.pl
our $var = "test";
require("inside.pm");

$ cat inside.pm 
print "Testing...\n";
print "$var\n";

$ perl out.pl
Testing...
test
```

This works because `our` makes `$var` global, and `inside.pm` is being executed in the scope with `$var` defined.  Not sure it is recommended technique, but it is an interesting question nevertheless!

**EDIT**: Need to clarify (okay patch) the answer based on a comment:

From [the documentation on the Perl function `our`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html):

> `our` associates a simple name with a package (read: global) variable in the current package, for use within the current lexical scope. In other words, `our` has the same scoping rules as `my` or `state`, but does not necessarily create a variable.

So using `our`, we get `$var` with the current package (here probably `main`) and we can use it in its scope.  In effect it is then "global" to the code in the file you are requiring-in.

A *true global* is introduced without the `our`, because variables default to global.  But I don't know anyone that would recommend them.

Comment: Not quite. `our` introduces a lexical (aliased to a global), not a global. That means the `our` variable is NOT visible outside of `out.pl`. The reason your example works has nothing to do with `our`. Take out the `our`, and it will still work.

Comment: +1 on the comment. Yes -- "global to the required-in code" is what I was thinking.  It is absoultely not a true global, which _would_ have been produced without the `our`.

Answer (score 5):

You are *always* using a package, even if you don't use the `package` declaration. By default, you're working in package `main`.

All variables you declare with `our` are package variables and should be available package wide. Here's an example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
# test2.pl

use strict;
use warnings;

our $foo = "bar";
1;
```

Since `$foo` is declared as a package variable, it will be available in other programs:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

require "test2.pl";

our $foo;
print "The value of \$foo is $foo\n";
```

Now I've given you enough rope, I'm going to tell you not to hang yourself with it.

This is a ***REALLY, REALLY BAD IDEA***. Notice that `$foo` gets a value from some sort of mysterious mechanism that's almost impossible to figure out?

Packages are *too complex*? Really? It's not that hard! Look at this example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
# test2.pm

package test2;
use strict;
use warnings;

our $foo = "bar";
1;
```

Not much different than before except I added the `package` declaration and now call my program `test2.pm` instead of `test2.pl`.

Here's how I access it:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use test2;

print "The value of \$foo from package test2 is $test2::foo\n";
```

All I had to do was use the package name in the variable. This is a ***BAD IDEA***, but it's way better than the ***REALLY, REALLY BAD IDEA*** shown above.

At least, you know where the value came from. It came from `test2.pm`. And, you could access the variable if you set it in a subroutine.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
# test2.pm

package test2;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub fooloader {
    our $foo = "bar";
}
1;
```

Notice that `$foo` is set in the subroutine `fooloader`. And, here's my other program to access it:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use test2;

&test2::fooloader();
print "The value of \$foo from package test2 is $test2::foo\n";
```

Now, you could use the Exporter to export your subroutines (and even variables), but that's not something you see too much anymore. Mainly because it is a ***REALLY BAD IDEA***. Not as bad as the original ***REALLY REALLY BAD IDEA***, but worse than the ***BAD IDEA*** above:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
# test2.pm

package test2;
use base qw(Exporter);

our @EXPORT = qw(fooloader);
use strict;
use warnings;

sub fooloader {
    our $foo = "bar";
}
1;
```

Now, I can use subroutine `fooloader` without the package name:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use test2;

fooloader();
print "The value of \$foo from package test2 is $test2::foo\n";
```

The problem, of course, is that you have no real idea where the subroutine `fooloader` is coming from. If you used `@EXPORT_OK` instead of `@EXPORT`, you could have then use `use test2 qw(fooloader);` and document where the `fooloader` function was coming from. It'll also help you to know not to create your own `fooloader` function in your own program and override the one you imported. Then, wonder why your program no longer works.

By the way, you could also export variables and not just functions. However, that becomes a ***REALLY, REALLY, REALLY BAD -- NO TERRIBLE IDEA*** because it violates every reason why you use packages in the first place. If you're going to do that, why bother with packages? Why not simple take a gun and shoot yourself in the foot?

The best and preferred way is to use object oriented Perl and do it in the ***THOROUGHLY CORRECT WAY***. A way where you know exactly what's going on and why. And, makes it easy to figure out what your code is doing. A way that keeps errors at a minimum.

Behold the thoroughly object oriented Test2 class:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
# Test2.pm

package Test2;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;

    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;

    return $self;
}

sub FooValue {
    return "bar";
}
1;
```

And using that `Test2` class:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Test2;

my $tester = Test2->new;

print "The value of foo from package test2 is " . $tester->FooValue . "\n";
```

The reason this is the best way to do it is because even if you use packages, you could manipulate the value of `$test2::foo` and it will be changed in your entire program. Imagine if this was say `$constants::pi` and somewhere you changed it from 3.14159 to 3. From then on, using `$constants::pi` would give you the wrong value. If you use the object oriented method, you couldn't change the value of the method Constant->Pi. It will always be 3.14159.

So, what did we learn today?

We learned that it is very easy in Perl to do something that's a ***REALLY, REALLY BAD IDEA***, but it doesn't take all that much work to use packages, so it merely becomes a ***BAD IDEA***. And, if you start learning a bit of object oriented Perl, you can actually, without too much effort, do it all in the ***THOROUGHLY CORRECT WAY***.

The choice is yours to make. Just remember the foot you're shooting will probably be your own.

Comment: +1 for explaining packages and showing what works/doesn't, -1 for "OO is the One True Way". You assert that calling `test2::fooloader` is a "really bad idea", while calling `test2->FooValue` is the "thoroughly correct way", even though the only difference between them is the extra value prepended to the parameter list when using `->` instead of `::`. (Oh, and you neither need nor (generally) want to prefix calls to subs with `&` ("`&test2::fooloader();`"), even if they're in another package. It's a Perl 4 holdover with non-obvious side-effects in Perl 5.)

Comment: @DaveSherohman: In the simple cases I present, OO doesn't make much difference. However, when a developer says "packages are too complex", it means they never advanced beyond what they learned in the Llama book. I can't blame them. Most Perl programmers find themselves stranded on little islands where they might be the only Perl programmer in the group. I want to explain to people stuff beyond the Llama book and tell them _See, it's not that difficult_. I've found that using OO programming technics make programming faster and less error prone, and I want to encourage others to learn it too.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but as I've said packages usage is overwhelming  my needs (for this case) and the answer is overwhelming the question.