# How do I use a variable in another Perl script?

Tags: perl

I know how to use a variable from one package to another in Perl. I am trying to use a global variable declared in `test1.pl` in another Perl script `test2.pl`. I am using `require` to load the perl file.

```
#!usr/bin/perl    #test1.pl
use strict;
use warnings;

out $db_name;   #global variable to be used in another script

fun();

sub fun
{
$db_name = 'xxyy';
}




#!usr/bin/perl    #test2.pl
require 'test1.pl';    #require is used to include the perl script like we use "use" for importing packages
my $database = $db_name;    #global variable from previous script
use strict;
use warnings;

testing();

sub testing
{
print "$database\n";
}
```

Comment: Its not `out`, its `our`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perl: how to make variables from requiring script available in required script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542120/perl-how-to-make-variables-from-requiring-script-available-in-required-script)

Comment: Actually that question doesn't have `warnings`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare the variables with `our` in both scripts.

```
# test1.pl
use strict;
use warnings;

our ( $foo );

$foo = 'bar';

# test2.pl
use strict;
use warnings;

our ( $foo );
require 'test1.pl';

print $foo; # bar
```

Your script `test2.pl` starts out in the `main` package because there is no `package` declaration. When you `require` a script that has no `package` in it, all the code will be loaded at the point where the `require` statement is. It will end up in the same package as the `require` line. So what's in `test1.pl` also ends up in the `main` package of the same Perl instance.

`our` declares a package *variable*. That means it's available as `$foo` inside of your package, and it's visible outside. And that is the trick here.

Stuff that is declared with `my $bar` inside of the `script1.pl` will end up in its own *scope* when the file is required, so the outer scope `script2.pl` cannot see that variable. But if you make it a package variable, it will be put into the package namespace, which is bigger.

We declare the package variable `our $foo` first, and then `require 'test1.pl'`. Inside of the other script, we do `our $foo` again, so there is no *`$foo` used only once* warning. The value of `'bar'` will end up in the package `$foo` (which is actually `$main::foo`, or `$::foo` if you ommit the name of the package. From there, it will be accessed later when printing `$foo`.

The order of the `our` and `require` doesn't really matter. But if you use globals, it makes sense to stick to some conventions, like listing all the global variables at the top of the script.

---

A word of advice: while this stuff seems to be *easy*, it is pretty outdated. Of course it works for small things, but it is hard to maintain.  Only use this stuff in legacy applications if it's already there and rewriting is too costly. You know about packages already. Use them instead!

Answer (score 10):

This is all far easier if you create a "real" module. Requiring libraries like that was a Perl 4 trick.

In DBName.pm, you have:

```
package DBName;

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw[$DBName];

our $DBName = 'xxyz';

1;
```

And in the calling program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use DBName;

sub testing {
  say $DBName;
}

testing();
```