# perl how to include a pre-defined variable list

Tags: perl, config, variable-assignment

Is it possible to have a perl file that defines a list of variables with certain values, and then have the main perl script include that file which contains the list of variable definitions?

Or any sort of perl approach which would make that intention work.

Thanks!

Comment: There are many ways to achieve desired goal. Please see [Q33230015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33230015/how-do-i-use-a-variable-in-another-perl-script) , [Config::General](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::General), [Config::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Tiny), [Config::INI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::INI), [Config::Any](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Any).

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to store configuration values as code. There are number of modules to help you maintain config files as others have mentioned. There's also JSON and YAML somewhere in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store those values in a config file and retrieve it using config parsing in your main perl script.
Refer following link for example.
https://perlmaven.com/reading-configuration-files-in-perl